# Permission Denied Issue in Perl - Need Solution

Tags: perl, permissions, directory, mkdir

I have a problem creating directories using Perl:

```
$country = 7;
$city = 12;   
$uploadFolder = "/opt/v-hosts/user/html/images/h_photos/ls";
$destination = $uploadFolder;
mkdir($destination) if(!-e $destination);
$destination .= "/$country";
mkdir($destination,0755) if(!-e $destination);
$destination .= "/$city";
mkdir($destination,0755) if(!-e $destination);
```

When I try to execute this code it should create the following directory:

> /opt/v-hosts/user/html/images/h_photos/ls/7/12

unfortunately the code returns an error:

> mkdir /opt/v-hosts/user/html/images/h_photos/ls/7: Permission denied at /opt/v-hosts/user/epbin/ls.cgi line 1376.\n

I tried to change the permission of `ls` file to **777** but it didn't solve the problem.

Comment: you havent enough rights for the `$uploadFolder`. Check `ls -l /opt/v-hosts/user/html/images/h_photos/`. So the `ls` forlder already exists, and you havent rights...

Comment: really I don't understand what you mean exactly.My question is how I can do to access the file then create new file in the sub directory?

Comment: yes. and the error message mean, you havent permissions.

Comment: In this case which file I must to change their permissions?

Comment: Check the permissions on every directory in the path `/opt/v-hosts/user/html/images/h_photos/`.  My guess is one of the intermediate directories is blocking you out.  Those intermediate directories do not need to be `rwx`, but they do at least need to be `x` for the uid your script runs as.

Comment: each file take the following permission user:775/html:775/images:777/h_photos:777/ls:777 all file marked as executed but the problem is still

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not a Perl error. The **/opt** folder or some subfolder is not writeable by the system-user who is responsible for the Apache or the CGI process.

```
$ perl -e 'use File::Path; $d=22; $city=7; mkpath "/tmp/moo/fooo/$city/$d";'
$ file /tmp/moo/foo/7/22
/tmp/moo/foo/7/22: directory
```

To fix your permissions, use `chown`. e.g:

```
$ ssh localhost chown apachDaemonUser /tmp/random
```